# Mean by factor level for last three rows

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe, which looks like this (but has more factor levels and values)

```
ID <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C")
Value <- rep(1:5)
test <- cbind.data.frame(ID, Value)
```

I would like to calculate the mean of the first 3 and last 3 values (rows) of each factor level.

For the first 3 values I used ddply:

```
library(plyr)    
mean_start <- ddply(test, .(ID), summarise, mean_start = mean(Value[1:3]))
```

This works great. But how can I refer to the last 3 rows, given that each factor level has a different amount of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `head`and `tail`:

```
library(plyr)    
(means <- ddply(test, .(ID), summarise, mean_start = mean(head(Value, 3)), mean_end = mean(tail(Value, 3))))
# ID mean_start mean_end
# 1  A   2.000000        4
# 2  B   2.000000        3
# 3  C   2.666667        4
```

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, as my actual data includes NAs at the beginning and end of each factor level, is there a way to ignore those, such that the mean of the first 3 rows after the last NA and of the last 3 rows before the first NA is calculated? I tried mean(head(Value, 3), na.rm=TRUE) but that didn't work..

Comment: @user3283824 There sure is. You can work your way through using `head` and `tail`. To get the mean of the first 3 rows after the last NA you could e.g. use `mean(head(tail(Value, -tail(which(is.na(Value)), 1)), 3))`. (You'd also have to check if there are `NA`s.)